# Press a button and do something based on your choosing in the dropdown menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried with this, but it is not working, I believe the error is in around the if statement=>

```
import tkinter as tk

from docx import Document

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Generator")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#dropdown part
# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)
choices = { 'broker','consultant','recruit'}
tkvar.set('broker') # set the default option
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices)
popupMenu.place(x=260,y=95)

def helloCallBack():

   if tkvar == 'broker':
      document = Document()
      document.add_heading("broker")
      document.save('0034.docx')

button = tk.Button(text="Generate", font=40, command=helloCallBack)
button.place(x=230, y=380)

root.mainloop()
```

Yes well... this is my problem, when I open the document I see no changes, or no added heading... I would like to have the documents heading changed to what I choose in the dropdown. Can anyone help?

Kr.
Selfiatus1

Comment: Unlike normal python strings, you need to use accessor methods with tkinter Variables. Try `if tkvar.get() == 'broker':`.

Comment: A huge thank you, it worked!! Thank you!